# Rollback sql file name convention of Flyway

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, flyway, data-migration

When using 'V1.0.0__Alter_Student_Schema.sql' for rollback scripts it worked. But when using 'R1.0.0__Alter_Student_Schema.sql' or 'U1.0.0__Alter_Student_Schema.sql' it gives '2 SQL migrations were detected but not run because they did not follow the filename convention.'

The Flyway documentation mentioned that R and U are possible in the file name.
[Documentation Link](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/rolling-back-138347144.html#:%7E:text=For%20rollbacks%20to%20work%2C%20an,any%20data%20manipulation%20is%20reversed.)

Spring Boot Version - 2.7.14

```
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>`
```

How to name Rollback scripts in the Rollback folder of Flyway?

Comment: Are you using Flyway Community or Flyway Teams? Undo scripts are a Teams only feature. (R scripts are for repeatable migrations, which are a different beast entirely)

Comment: I'm Using this maven dependency 
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
 <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

The OSS version of flyway doesn't have support for [undo scripts](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/undo-184127463.html), which explains that one. You'll need a Teams license for this, which needs a [different maven dependency](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/maven-goal-184127408.html). For the R (repeatable) migrations, your naming is wrong. The naming should be R__Add_new_table.sql (ie no version number). [More detail here](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/migrations-184127470.html).

Answer (score 0):

Changed the flyway-core dependency to `flyway-commandline`. Renamed all rollback scripts according to the `R__Add_new_table.sql` format.